# Is there a SE site to ask patent related questions that is off topic here?

Tags: support

I want to ask about why doesn't patent infringer just remove the infringing features if they are not that important to their products. For example, in the [Samsung-Apple](https://www.cnet.com/tech/mobile/apple-v-samsung-patent-trial-recap-how-it-all-turned-out-faq) smartphone patent war, the software patents all seems very not essential for Samsung's success and removing them is not very hard, why doesn't Samsung just remove them to prevent the long-lasting war?

This seems to be off topic there, and also off topic on SE Law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just asking this question on the regular Ask Patents SE site (not the Meta). I don't see why it should be off topic.